# Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.yy'. Expected a suffix in this list: ['.lm', '.ll']

Tags: c++, c, yacc, scons, juniper

I'm having an issue while building packages from source using scons. I'm getting the below exception. If I change the file extension to ll or lm
I get syntax errors while it compiles.

```
scons -j ${JOBS_COUNT:-$(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo || echo 1)} --without-dpdk

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
('Ubuntu', '20.04', 'focal')
('Ubuntu', '20.04', 'focal')
('Ubuntu', '20.04', 'focal')

scons: *** While building `['sandeshy.cc']' from `['/root/salim/src/contrail-common/sandesh/compiler/sandeshy.yy']': Don't know how to build from a source file with suffix `.yy'.  Expected a suffix in this list: ['.lm', '.ll'].
```

### Sconscript file

```
# -*- mode: python; -*-
  
#
# Created by Megh Bhatt on 07/16/12.
# Copyright (c) 2012 Contrail Systems. All rights reserved.
#

Import('SandeshEnv')

env = SandeshEnv.Clone();

rmflags = ['-Wsign-compare', '-Werror', '-fno-exceptions',
           '--coverage']

cflags = env['CCFLAGS']
for flag in rmflags:
    if flag in cflags:
        cflags.remove(flag)

env['CCFLAGS'] = cflags

env.Append(CPPPATH = ['#src/contrail-common/sandesh/compiler','#build/include'])

# Lex and Yacc
env.Append(YACCFLAGS = '-d')
env['YACCHXXFILESUFFIX'] = '.hh'
#env.Append(LEXFLAGS = '-DSANDESH')
env.CXXFile(target = 'sandeshy.cc', source = 'sandeshy.yy')
env.CXXFile(target = 'sandeshl.cc', source = 'sandeshl.ll')

sandesh = env.Program(target = 'sandesh',
                      source = ['main.cc',
                                'md5.c',
                                'sandeshy.cc',
                                'sandeshl.cc',
                                'generate/t_cpp_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_html_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_xsd_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_c_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_py_generator.cc',
                                'generate/t_doc_generator.cc',
                                'parse/parse.cc',
                               ])
env.Install(env['TOP_BIN'], sandesh)
```

I am trying to build packages from opencontrail source files which is got from github repo

[sandeshy.yy](https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-sandesh/blob/R5.0/compiler/sandeshy.yy) file located in github repo

Comment: Might help if you showed (some of) the contents of the `.yy` file.

Comment: It defines a parser for Yacc or Bison (the GNU version of Yacc) to generate. Or maybe it's for Lex, a tool used in conjunction with Yacc/Bison. I can't remember which.

Comment: Do you have yacc installed?

Comment: Thanks man i was missing bison packages in my pc  , again Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You need to install yacc to fix this error, scons is presumably checking what it is able to process, as it can't process yacc files it doesn't add `.yy` to the list of supported extensions for `CXXFile`